# Django url tag and query string

Tags: django

Cannot make url with query strings in django template: Here is example:

```
<a href="{% url getFormMetaData %}?code=RHJ6YXZh">Form</a>
```

and urls.py file looks like this:

```
url(r'^main/getFormMetaData/$', views.getFormMetaData, name='getFormMetaData'),
```

Comment: Alo i tried in url tag "views.getFormMetaData" ....

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: 'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.

Comment: And did you see the docs? They explain it completely. Plus, this has nothing to do with the query string.

Comment: Yes i saw the docs but no success for now...

Answer (score 1):

You need to put single quotes around `getFormMetaData`. Not using quotes was acceptable in previous version of Django, but that has now been deprecated.

Thus, your code should be:

```
<a href="{% url 'getFormMetaData' %}?code=RHJ6YXZh">Form</a>
```

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: Hm now i'm getting Reverse for 'getFormMetaData' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: Some Django projects use a "multi-site" directory structure. Typically there is a folder that contains top level URLs, settings, and wsgi script contents. Are you properly including your *site's* URLs in that top level URL locator file?

Comment: Hmm, in that case, could you double check that you are referring to the correct view? If your view function is contained directly in `views.py` then `views.getFormMetaData` is correct. But, if it's contained in a file that is within a `views` directory then you will need to say `views.some_filename.getFormMetaData`.

Comment: Function is directly in views.py, i will check again does link works

Comment: Make sure that your view signature expects no parameters (except for the standard `request` that is passed in. Thus, your view should read: `def getFormMetaData(request):`. If there are more arguments to the function then you must pass that as a parameter in the URL template call.

Comment: Additionally, try using django.core.urlresolvers.reverse at the command line for a (possibly) better error:
`>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`
`>>> reverse('views.getFormMetaData')`

Comment: Also check to see if you have more than one url that points to that view

Answer (score 0):

I must answer my own question...

Something really not good here...

in that urls.py file i have something like this:

```
url(r'^main/$', views.main, name='main'),
url(r'^main/getFormMetaData/$', views.getFormMetaData, name='getFormMetaData'),
```

These url tags i have in main.html. I can access to main.html like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/TestProjekat/main/
```

Now, how to pass an one or two arguments in getFormMetaData from main.html.. How to wrote url tags?

Comment: Per the Django documentation: `{% url 'namedURL' v1 v2 %}`. Alternatively, you may name the arguments: `{% url 'namedURL' arg1=v1 arg2=v2 %}`.

Comment: I saw that but dont know how to use it :)

Comment: AAAAA solved! in top level urls.py i have namespace. I removed it and now works! :) Thanks for answers!